# Mail_form Rails - Messages Sends in Rails C - not from form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mail-form

Using the Mail_form Gem in rails, I can verify that my mail configuration is correct; however I don't receive any errors in my logs.

**contact.rb [app/models/contact.rb]**

```
   class Contact < MailForm::Base
include MailForm::Delivery

   attribute :name,      :validate => true
    attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
    attribute :message
   attribute :nickname, :captcha => false

 # Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
  # in ActionMailer accepts.
 def headers
{
  :subject => "IT Site Contact",
  :to => "kompinski@gmail.com",
  :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
     }
    end
   end
```

**contacts_controller.rb**

```
   class ContactsController < ApplicationController 
   def new 
@contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])  
end 
 def create 
@contact = Contact.new(params[:contact])
@contact.request = request 
@contact.deliver 
  end
 end
```

**routes.rb**

```
    resources :contacts, only: [:new, :create]
    get 'contact' => 'contacts#new'
   post 'contact' => 'contacts#create'
```

**new.html.erb [/views/contacts/new.html.erb]**

```
    <div class="container">
<div class="col-md-6"><h2>Contact us</h2>
<hr />
<form role="form">  
   <%= twitter_bootstrap_form_for @contact, url: new_contact_path, method: :post do |f| %>
   <div class="medium">

    </div>
   <div class="medium">
  <%= f.text_field :name, :required => true %>
 </div>
 <div class="medium">

  <%= f.email_field :email, :required => false %>
   </div>

<div class="medium">

  <%= f.text_area :message, :as => :text, :required => true %>
    </div>

   <div class="btn">
  <%= f.submit 'Submit' %>
  <% end %>
  </div>

  </form>

    </div>
   </div>
```

** Edit **
Also I can send it directly from the form by using Contact.new(params[:contact]).deliver, but only when resubmit the address; however when I load the page containing the form it indicates 'undefined method `model_name' for TrueClass:Class'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code worked for my controller where the issue seemed to be:

```
   def new
  @contact = Contact.new
   if 
  Contact.new(params[:contact]).deliver
redirect_to '/contacts/thanks', :alert => ["Yeah!"]
  end
```